# Motivation -> Psychology-of-writing retagging trouble

Tags: support, status-completed, retagging

I've started retagging The questions under [motivation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motivation) that were about writer's motivation to [psychology-of-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology-of-writing), so that [motivation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motivation) could remain for character motivation only. (Doesn't make sense to have both under the same tag.)

Came upon this question: [What should step one in writing a novel be?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/583/14704) It should be retagged, and also get [getting-started](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/getting-started). Trouble is, **it's locked**, so tags can't be changed on it.

Can a moderator take care of this?

Edit: finished all the others, and adjusted the [motivation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motivation) tag wiki.

Comment: So you feel that question should be [tag:psychology-of-writing] [tag:creative-writing] [tag:getting-started]? If you could specify the exact set of tags you feel it should have, I'm sure one of us can get that done quickly; thing is, it should almost certainly be re-locked quickly after the change is made.

Comment: @aCVn Yes, exactly. Thanks!

Comment: I've added the tag.